# Wrapping individual function calls in Python

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm writing a script that requests some data from an IMAP server using the `imaplib` library. Having initiated a connection (`c`), I make the following calls:

```
rv, data = c.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, EMAIL_PASS)
if rv != 'OK':
    print('login error')
else:
    print(rv, data)

rv, mailboxes = c.list()
if rv != 'OK':
    print('mailbox error')
else:
    print(rv, data)

rv, data = c.select(EMAIL_FOLDER)
if rv != 'OK':
    print('folder error')
else:
    print(rv, data)
```

How could I rewrite this to use some sort of a wrapper function to reuse the logic of checking the error code and printing the data? I assume the function would take an error message as an argument and also the command to execute (`select`, `login`, etc.). How could I call a select connection function by passing it's name in an argument?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Yes, you could write a wrapper function (`rv, data = handle_error(c.login(...))`) and/or pass in the name of the method to another function. What have you tried, and what's the problem with it?

Comment: `def check(rv, data, msg): ...` and use as `check(rv, data, 'folder error')`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Basically, I want to simplify this into a single function that would take the action (select, list, login) as argument along with an error message. Can I pass the function call (e.g. `c.list()`) as an argument to the "handle" function?

Comment: Yes, as long as you pass the method itself (`c.list`, note lack of parentheses); they're first class in Python. But then you need to handle the arguments correctly.

Comment: You may want to look into python decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-use any code, look at the things that stay the same (e.g. the fact that `rv` and `data` come out of your `imaplib` calls in that order, and that `rv=='OK'` means things are OK) and write the logic that involves them, once. Then look at the things that change (e.g. the exact error message that needs to be printed). Parameterize the things that change, as in this example where the `description` argument changes the error message:

```
def check(description, rvdata):
    rv, data = rvdata
    if rv == 'OK':
        print(data)
        return data
    else:
        print(description + ' error')
        return None

data = check('login', c.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, EMAIL_PASS))
mailboxes = check('mailbox', c.list())
selection = check('folder', c.select(EMAIL_FOLDER))
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I understood you would like to check Decorators for your task.

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, error_message):
        self.error_message = error_message

    def __call__(self, wrapped):
        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            rv, data = wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
            if rv=="OK":
                return(rv, data)
            else:
                print(self.error_message)
                return(rv, data)
        return func

@Wrapper("Folder Error")
def select(email_folder):
    return "OK", "OLOLO"

@Wrapper("Folder Error")
def select_err(email_folder):
    return "FAIL", "OLOLO"

print select("")
print select_err("")
```

yields

```
('OK', 'OLOLO')
Folder Error
('FAIL', 'OLOLO')
```

You can check reply inside of Wrapper's `__call__` function and treat it the way you want to. For exampl you can return "False" or raise errors if `rv` not equals to "OK"

But It might be overly complicated for your case.

Comment: Yes, a little bit too complicated. But thank you for the alternative approach nevertheless!

Comment: I had never thought of using object instances as decorators before.  That's a pretty cool trick.

Comment: @jez, I had a really hard time understanding decorators at first and only recently finally realized how to use it. I looked this trick up somewhere)